# Swagger refer a response to a Spring object, paging with Swagger

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, swagger

In my project I generate all controller endpoints using Swagger template, I'm trying to implement an endpoint which returns Spring's `Page` object instead of a list.

That's what I have:

```
responses:
        200:
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/definitions/Metadata'
```

And it generates:

```
public ResponseEntity<List<Metadata>> getMetadataList()
```

But I want Swagger to generate a response with Spring's `Page` instead of a list:

```
public ResponseEntity<Page<Metadata>> getMetadataList()
```

How can I refer in Swagger template to Spring's Page object? Do I have to define my own Page object and then map Spring's Page to my object?

Answer (score 0):

Attached generated swagger api docs with Page object.

[swagger](https://api.myjson.com/bins/oaemx)

```
responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          schema:
           $ref: '#/definitions/Page%C2%ABMetadata%C2%BB'
        '401':
          description: Unauthorized
        '403':
          description: Forbidden
        '404':
          description: Not Found
definitions:
  Metadata:
    type: object
    properties:
      data:
        type: string
    title: Metadata
  Pageable:
    type: object
    properties:
      offset:
        type: integer
        format: int64
      pageNumber:
        type: integer
        format: int32
      pageSize:
        type: integer
        format: int32
      paged:
        type: boolean
      sort:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Sort'
      unpaged:
        type: boolean
    title: Pageable
  Page«Metadata»:
    type: object
    properties:
      content:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/Metadata'
      empty:
        type: boolean
      first:
        type: boolean
      last:
        type: boolean
      number:
        type: integer
        format: int32
      numberOfElements:
        type: integer
        format: int32
      pageable:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Pageable'
      size:
        type: integer
        format: int32
      sort:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Sort'
      totalElements:
        type: integer
        format: int64
      totalPages:
        type: integer
        format: int32
    title: Page«Metadata»
  Sort:
    type: object
    properties:
      empty:
        type: boolean
      sorted:
        type: boolean
      unsorted:
        type: boolean
    title: Sort
```

Comment: But this is an object created based on Spring's Page, with this I still have to map Spring's Page to this object. Is it possible to have in Swagger a reference like this: `#/definitions/org.springframework.data.domain.Page`? With this solution with every object I need to make a new definition of Page<?> ?